# How do I create encrypted partitions with kickstart in Debian or Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, kickstart

I am setting up an automated installation of Ubuntu using kickstart and network booting.
With redhat this works quite well, however Ubuntu kickstart appears rather limited and I can not find documentation describing the options available.

The most important one for me that appears missing is:

> --encrypted

i.e.:

> part /home --size=35000 --grow --fstype=xfs --encrypted

In order to create encrypted partitions. However the installer complains the option --encrypted is unrecognised, and continues with unencrypted partitions.

Is there a way to automate creating encrypted partitions through kickstart for Ubuntu (and Debian)?

In addition is there any documentation available that describes the kickstart options available for Ubuntu and Debian? I am aware of redhat's documentation in that regard, however it's of limited use in this case due to missing or different functionality.

Comment: With Debian/Ubuntu, you're really better off using preseed files.  The kickstart support in them isn't great, and lacks a lot of of functionality.

Comment: I know, not my choice...

Comment: They do have a special option you can use to specify preseed values.  I'd suggest looking into that.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that. I think I am going with preseeding since it doesn't seem like there is a solution. If you like to put your comments in an answer I can use that as the accepted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the kickstart support in Debian/Ubuntu is pretty lacking.  For anything other then basic configuration you're going to need to switch to using preseed files instead.

There is a special option in the kickstart file that will let you embed some preseed options, which might be your best bet (if you don't want to completely switch to preseed).

Comment: Probably going with preseeding completely, since I have working files lying around. As an aside you need the alternate install CD in case you want to use full disk encryption.